# Почему не выполняется get запрос в script.google.com?

Tags: google-apps-script

Написал код для https://script.google.com/ который в google sheet читает значение ячейки A1 и при вызове его по ссылке полученной после развёртывания:

[https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyD-zaKскрылYu1/exec](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyD-zaK%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BBYu1/exec)

возвращает в браузере содержимое ячейки А1. То есть выполняет Get запрос (мне именно get запросом и нужно получать)

Собственно сам код для https://script.google.com :

```
function doGet(e)  {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15hEM1czkCDскрыл5_6OHxXv88").getSheetByName("Лист1");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var value = cell.getValue();
  Logger.log(value);
}
```

Но при вызове полученной ссылки в браузере вижу: **Скрипт был выполнен, но ничего не возвратил.** Хотя в самом окне https://script.google.com/ норм  в логе показывает содержимое А1.

**Вопрос:** почему в get запрос не скидывает полученные данные?

Comment: Потому что вы этого не написали?

Comment: Не забывайте отмечать ответы как решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция должна вернуть ожидаемый контент

либо

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(value)
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

либо

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(value);
```

Очень сильно зависит от выбранной вами модели приложения.

Comment: Спасибо кто помог)
 Сделал так и все заработало:
[CODE]function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15hEM1czkCDs22**скрыл****5FyZVYGnh5_6OHxXv88");
  const tmpl = sheet.getSheetByName('Лист1');
  const range = tmpl.getRange("A1:A");
  var rangeValues = range.getValues();
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(rangeValues))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}[/CODE]